# HTTP StatusCode 000 when it should be 200 on server for the cURL in shell script

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using CURL to get StatusCode at Windows Putty on Linux.

When I try with:

`curl -k -I  <url>`

it gives 200 which is fine:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Language: en-US`

but when I try code below to get only StatusCode number, it gives 000:

`curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' <url>`

response: `000`

What is the issue here?

Comment: Relevant question on SuperUser : https://superuser.com/questions/501690/curl-http-code-of-000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL 000 means server did not respond. It can be due to Firewall blockage, or you are using on localhost or ca issue.

Answer (score 0):

000 more likely means you faced with untrusted certificate issue. Try to add back -k key and you'll get 200